# Tables created in Zeppelin are not visible in JDBC connection view of VORA

Tags: vora

We have created the table CUSTOMER through zeppelin interface of VORA. Now I want to access this CUSTOMER via SAP LUMIRA . After starting the thrift server , we logged into JDBC connector command prompt using beeline as suggested in developer guide. 
When I connected Lumira to JDBC connector , under CATALOG_VIEW , I can not find my table named CUSTOMER. 
I tried to register the table CUSTOMER again under JDBC connector prompt but its gave error message.

Is it not possible to access same VORA table created using zeppelin interface in JDBC connection ?

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7qnW.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Vora are you using? Connectivity to Lumira is only supported as of Vora 1.1. 
If you use Ambari to manage the Vora installation you can check the version at 'Admin' -> 'Stacks and Versions'.

Comment: Its working now.... I passed attribute "namenoderul" in register table command , and table was visible under CATALOG _VIEW in lumira.

Answer (score 0):

Its working now.... I passed attribute "namenoderul" in register table command , and table is visible under CATALOG _VIEW in lumira.